# Apply class only to last element with specific class?

Tags: css

See example here:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="group">Test</div>
  <div class="group">Test</div>
  <div class="group">Test</div>
</div>

.wrapper {

}

.group {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper > .group {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper > .group ~ .group {
    border-top: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0j984bg3/22/

I successfully apply a border top only to the first element with the `group` class using:

```
.wrapper > .group {
    border-top: 1px solid black;

}

.wrapper > .group ~ .group {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Is there any similar hack for applying a css rule only to the last element with a specific class? In my case I want to apply `border-bottom: 1px solid black;` only to the last element with the `group` class.

Note:

I know that there are work arounds like last-of-type where I insert something like an empty tag of other type before and after the group. I don't want to use work-arounds. I want to use last-of-class somehow.

Comment: You Mean like this, https://jsfiddle.net/0j984bg3/21/

Comment: the answer is easy : you cannot, you have to use workaround because there is no selector like `lasy-of-class`